# Best practice for blocking mode of listening socket and client socket?

Tags: sockets, blocking

listening socket is responsible for accepting new coming client socket :

```
sock_client = accept(sock_listen, NULL, NULL)
```

In a typical C/S application,what's the best choice of blocking mode of listening socket and client socket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are threaded and can devote a thread to a socket, then blocking.   If you are not, then on the server non-blocking.  On the client it depends if you have something better to do.  Blocking if not, non-block if you do.

Comment: I agree with the listening socket;But for the client socket part, can you elaborate more about it?

Comment: Consider a client application like ftp.  When ftp is attempting to run the command requested by the user, it doesn't need to do anything else.  If the user wants to interrupt, ^C sends a signal which interrupts blocking I/O.  Compare this to a web browser talking to the same ftp site.  The web browser has to listen for button presses, probably animate some gifs, handle graphical refresh requests, check the RSS feed, etc all while doing the ftp protocol.  The first case can use blocking I/O.  The second needs to use non-blocking (assuming it was non-threaded).

Comment: @DriverBoy: links/lynx/curl/wget might not be.  And before you say it, even though curl might not be animating a gif, it is/may be still spinning the progress bar and calculating download speed even when waiting for network I/O.  But yes, in general they are threaded.